# GRASS GIS 3D - Inconsistent number of attributes

Tags: grass-gis, error, 3d, fields-attributes

I am trying to automate my 3D plotting of GRASS GIS 7 results, also to make them more consistent in size and view angles. So for

```
m.nviz.image elevation_map=DEM -a mode=fine resolution_fine=1 color_map=result position=0.84,0.16 height=2799 perspective=24 twist=0 zexag=1.000000 focus=119,49,2713 light_position=0.74,-0.57,0.80 light_brightness=80 light_ambient=20 light_color=255:255:255 output=nviz_output format=ppm size=1853,989
```

I get as error:

```
ERROR: Inconsistent number of attributes (<vpoint> 0: <vpoint_position> 3)
```

I do not seem to be the first with this problem, but could not find an answer yet how to solve this problem. I have no vector data in my workspace, so why is vpoint here an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Upgrade to rev 60724.